# thread-safety of primitive concurrent read and write

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

- Simplified illustration below, how does .NET deal with such a situation?
- and if it would cause problems, would i have to lock/gate access to each and every field/property that might at times be written to + accessed from different threads?

#### A field somewhere

```
public class CrossRoads(){
    public int _timeouts;
}
```

#### A background thread writer

```
public void TimeIsUp(CrossRoads crossRoads){
    crossRoads._timeouts++;
}
```

#### Possibly at the same time, trying to read elsewhere

```
public void HowManyTimeOuts(CrossRoads crossRoads){
    int timeOuts = crossRoads._timeouts;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simple answer is that the above code has the ability to cause problems if accessed simultaneously from multiple threads.

The .Net framework provides two solutions: interlocking and thread synchronization.

For simple data type manipulation (i.e. ints), interlocking using the [Interlocked class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) will work correctly and is the recommended approach.

In fact, interlocked provides specific methods (Increment and Decrement) that make this process easy:

Add an IncrementCount method to your CrossRoads class:

```
public void IncrementCount() {
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _timeouts);
}
```

Then call this from your background worker:

```
public void TimeIsUp(CrossRoads crossRoads){
    crossRoads.IncrementCount();
}
```

The reading of the value, unless of a 64-bit value on a 32-bit OS, are atomic. See the [Interlocked.Read method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.read.aspx) for more detail.

For class objects or more complex operations, you will need to use thread [synchronization locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (lock in C# or SyncLock in VB.Net).

This is accomplished by creating a static synchronization object at the level the lock is to be applied (for example, inside your class), obtaining a lock on that object, and performing (only) the necessary operations inside that lock:

```
    private static object SynchronizationObject = new Object();

    public void PerformSomeCriticalWork()
    {
        lock (SynchronizationObject)
        {
            // do some critical work
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The good news is that reads and writes to ints are guaranteed to be atomic, so no torn values. However, it is not guaranteed to do a safe ++, and the read could potentially be cached in registers. There's also the issue of instruction re-ordering.

I would use:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref crossroads._timeouts);
```

For the write, which will ensure no values are lost, and;

```
int timeouts = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref crossroads._timeouts, 0, 0);
```

For the read, since this observes the same rules as the increment. Strictly speaking "volatile" is probably enough for the read, but it is so poorly understood that the Interlocked seems (IMO) safer. Either way, we're avoiding a lock.

Comment: Unless `TimeIsUp` is called in multiple threads, the code is safe, no need for locking mechanism.(`HowManyTimeOuts` can be called any time, before,after or in the middle of increment in `TimeIsUp`). It is always correct at the time it is called

Comment: @L.B actually no; in a tight loop, it could stay on a register and not ever hit the field. An edge. Ase,  it worth mentioning. To be robust it needs either a volatile read, an interlock, or a fence.

Comment: +1 the read should use interlocked too to provide a freshness guarantee. The other solutions do not mention this. You can also use Interlocked.Add(0).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not a C# developer, but this is how it typically works at this level:

> how does .NET deal with such a situation?

Unlocked. Not likely to be guaranteed to be atomic.

> Would i have to lock/gate access to each and every field/property that might at times be written to + accessed from different threads?

Yes. An alternative would be to make a lock for the object available to the clients, then tell the clients they must lock the object while using the instance. This will reduce the number of locks acquisitions, and guarantee a more consistent, predictable, state for your clients.

Answer (score 3):

Forget dotnet. At the machine language level, `crossRoads._timeouts++` will be implemented as an `INC [memory]` instruction. This is known as a Read-Modify-Write instruction. These instructions are atomic with respect to multi-threading on a single processor*, (essentially implemented with time-slicing,) but are not atomic with respect to multi-threading using multiple processors or multiple cores.

So:

If you can guarantee that only `TimeIsUp()` will ever modify `crossRoads._timeouts`, and if you can guarantee that only one thread will ever execute `TimeIsUp()`, then it will be safe to do this. The writing in `TimeIsUp()` will work fine, and the reading in `HowManyTimeOuts()` (and any place else) will work fine. But if you also modify `crossRoads._timeouts` elsewhere, or if you ever spawn one more background thread writer, you will be in trouble.

In either case, my advice would be to play it safe and lock it.

(*) They are atomic with respect to multi-threading on a single processor because context switches between threads happen on a periodic interrupt, and on the x86 architectures these instructions are atomic with respect to interrupts, meaning that if an interrupt occurs while the CPU is executing such an instruction, the interrupt will wait until the instruction completes. This does not hold true with more complex instructions, for example those with the REP prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Although an `int` may be 'native' size to a CPU (dealing in 32 or 64 bits at a time), if you are reading and writing from different threads to the same variable, you are best off locking this variable and synchronizing access.

There is never a *guarantee* that reads/writes maybe atomic to an `int`.

You can also use `Interlocked.Increment` for your purposes here.

Comment: Actually, it **is** guaranteed to be atomic, in the language spec. Long and double are not, for example, although references **are** ( guaranteed to be atomic), regardless of the platform.

Comment: @competent_tech because while reads and writes are individually guaranteed to be atomic, that does not mean that an increment (comprising several operations, including a read and a write) is atomic as a composite. You, however, state that reads/writes are not guaranteed to be atomic: they are.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Of course, sorry for the waste of time. I was thinking that this was in response to ++, not the individual read and write ops.